# Kendo-Template set local file

Tags: javascript, kendo-template

I've here an code from a Kendo-Template. The Code gets the Product.js file online, I've downloaded it but i could not figure it out how to implement it local.

Here the Code:

```
  (function() {

      var app = window.app = window.app || {};
      var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products";

      app.products = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
          read:  {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
            dataType: "jsonp"
          }
        }
      });
   ... //rest of code
```

Content of Products.js:

```
callback([{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Chai","UnitPrice":18,"UnitsInStock":39,"Discontinued":false},{"ProductID":2,"ProductName":"Chang","UnitPrice":19,"UnitsInStock":17,"Discontinued":false}])
```

tryed also the local data virtualization description from: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-listview/local-virtualization
but no chance
thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have Done a Demo in jsfiddle for Local Data

```
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);

 //create datasource
 var movieDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     data: [{
         name: "Jane Doe",
         age: "30",
         letter: "A"
     }, {
         name: "John Doe",
         age: "33",
         letter: "B"
     }]
 });

 //instantiate the list view 
 function loadListView() {
     $("#listView").kendoMobileListView({
         dataSource: movieDataSource,
         template: $("#listviewTemplate").html(),
         filterable: {
             field: "age",
             operator: "startswith"
         }
     });
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chanaka1/x09tk3xm/2/